# How do I retrieve the user ID of the latest editor of a node?

Tags: 8

I know how to get the user who created a node after getting the node object.

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$uid = $node->getOwnerId();
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
```

Since an alternative to retrieving values of the node object is for example `$node->nid->value`, I tried to get the revision user ID this way.

```
$ruid = $node->revision_uid->value;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, although I see with the Devel module that there is a value. So what is the equivalent in Drupal 8 to `$node->revision_uid` in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$node->getOwnerID()` returns the user ID for the user who created the node. If you need the user who created the revision, you need to use [`$node->getRevisionUser()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionLogInterface.php/function/RevisionLogInterface%3A%3AgetRevisionUser/8.6.x), or [`$node->getRevisionUserId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionLogInterface.php/function/RevisionLogInterface%3A%3AgetRevisionUserId/8.6.x) for the user ID.

Comment: Great, thanks. So I suppose I will try the "set…" and "get…" found in node class member names on this page the next time: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/8.6.x

Comment: That page lists all the methods available for the `Node` class, including the ones defined in a parent class, or a trait used by the class. So, yes, that is the first place to look. It's not always that quick to find the right method to use, but it's a start.